# Image not loading in react

Tags: reactjs, webpack

My image is not loading in react and I have the following in my webpack config:

```
use: {
    loader: 'url-loader'
},
test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/,
```

I don't get errors but the image is just displaying alt `not working`

```
<img src={require("./Images/start.jpg")} alt="not working" />
```

My complete config

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            use: {

                loader: "babel-loader"
            },
            test: /\.js$|jsx/,
            exclude: /node_modules/

        },
        {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your webpack config file try using this loader:

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: No, still not. I installed the ```file-loader``` package also.

Comment: I think so, I updated my config and posted now. Still not working

Comment: Is there something missing? It is still not working.